# Push route to parent component inside a function (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, router

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious but I can't figure it out. Please help!
I have the following routes defined:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Login',
    component: () => import('../views/Login.vue'),
    meta: {
      authRedirect: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/companies',
    name: 'Companies',
    component: () => import('../views/Companies.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/companies/:id',
    name: 'Company',
    component: () => import('../views/Company.vue'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: '404',
    component: () => import('../views/404.vue')
  }
]
```

Then I have the following in my component:

```
export default {
  name: 'Company',
  data() {
    return {
      company: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCompanyDetails: function() {
      let self = this
      axios.get('/api/companies/' + this.$route.params.id).then(function(response) {
        self.company = response.data
      }).catch(function() {
        self.$router.push('companies')
      })
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getCompanyDetails()
  }
}
```

Essentially everything is working if the API returns data, but inside the `catch` function I'm trying to push the route back to **/companies**. But it's redirecting to **/companies/companies**. How do I redirect it to the correct route?

Comment: you are missing forward slash.. `self.$router.push('/companies')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried `$router.push('/companies')` (with a **/** in the path) ?

Also, you can use `$router.push({ name: 'Companies' })` if you want to make it more clear, it will match the `name` defined in your routes.